# testing rest api using postman

Tags: chatter-rest-api

```
{
    "message": "The HTTP entity body is required, but this request has no entity body.",
    "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
}
```

hi,,help me,how to resolve this error.i got this error while inserting data using webservices api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input parameters must be sent in body in form,otherwise u will get above error.